# Need to add to my grocery list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on list that propagates the browser with a grocery list that is created in my Javascript file using an object and in calculates the total of the list and the price. The problem that I am running into is the additional function that I want to add on in which you input the grocery item and its price. After the the two are added you press the submit button in the form and it adds itself to the grocery list. My addList() function is not working correctly.

```js
//Second Commit
//Created variables that get several ID's to place list object array
var Cart = document.getElementById("basketItems");

// 2 variables were created to get id in input tags to take input new item and price and add to things array

//created groceries object that holds things array and object function to calculate total of prices
var groceries ={
things: [
    {item:"Chicken", price:4.65},
        {item:"Tomato",price:.68},
        {item:"Pasta",price:3.68},
        {item:"cheese",price:2.99},
],
total: function(){
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i<=this.things.length-1; i++){
sum = this.things[i].price +sum}
return sum;
}
};


console.log(a);

//set for loop for things array to display as string in #basketItems section
for (var i = 0; i<=groceries.things.length-1; i++) {
 Cart.innerHTML+= (groceries.things[i].item + " : " + groceries.things[i].price ) + "<br>";
  /*console.log(groceries.things[i].item + " : " + groceries.things[i].price);*/
};
// placing variable a & b from input box into things array into the html

//appending Cart variable into parent section to display things array

//inputting total object into html that calculates total price of things array
Cart.innerHTML += groceries.total();
console.log(groceries.total());
function addList(){
 document.getElementById("basketItems").innerHTML = "";

 var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
 var b = document.getElementById("b").value*1;
 var NewItem = {item:a, price:b};
 if (a !="") {
  groceries.things.push(NewItem)
 }
 

};
```

```css
html,body,ul, li, p{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;


} 
header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
#basket{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: gray;
 text-align: center;
}
#basketItems{
 margin: 40px 0px 0px 20px;
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 border: white solid 3px;
 text-align: center;
}
form{
 margin: 40px 50px 0px 50px;
 float: left;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 border: white solid 3px;
 text-align: center;
}
#a{
 background-color: none;
 border: solid white 2px;
}
#b{
 background-color: none;
 border: solid white 2px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Groceries</h1>
 </header>
 <section id="basket">
  <section id="basketItems"></section>
  <form>
      ITEM:
     <input id="a" type="text" id name="firstname"><br>
     PRICE:
     <input id="b" type="text" name="lastname">
     <button onclick="addList()">Button</button>
  </form>
 </section>
 <footer></footer>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a id attribute two times in the first input that is invalid

Comment: also your form has no method and no action. So what is it supposed ot do on submit?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to re-add the items to the DOM after you removed them. In this case I wrapped the logic that is responsible for it in a function called `foo()` and call it at the end of the `addList()` function and once when the page has loaded in.

Further more as @Lelio Faieta pointed out the form is trying to submit the changes, which will result in a page reload. This can be cancelled out by using `e.preventDefault()` or by setting the type of your button to `type="button"`.

Example below:

```js
//Second Commit
//Created variables that get several ID's to place list object array
var Cart = document.getElementById("basketItems");

// 2 variables were created to get id in input tags to take input new item and price and add to things array

//created groceries object that holds things array and object function to calculate total of prices
var groceries = {
  things: [{
      item: "Chicken",
      price: 4.65
    },
    {
      item: "Tomato",
      price: .68
    },
    {
      item: "Pasta",
      price: 3.68
    },
    {
      item: "cheese",
      price: 2.99
    },
  ],
  total: function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.things.length - 1; i++) {
      sum = this.things[i].price + sum
    }
    return sum;
  }
};


foo();

function foo() {

  for (var i = 0; i <= groceries.things.length - 1; i++) {
    Cart.innerHTML += (groceries.things[i].item + " : " + groceries.things[i].price) + "<br>";
  };
  Cart.innerHTML += groceries.total();
}

function addList() {
  document.getElementById("basketItems").innerHTML = "";

  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value * 1;
  var NewItem = {
    item: a,
    price: b
  };
  if (a != "") {
    groceries.things.push(NewItem);
    foo();
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body,
ul,
li,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#basket {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

#basketItems {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: white solid 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin: 40px 50px 0px 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: white solid 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

#a {
  background-color: none;
  border: solid white 2px;
}

#b {
  background-color: none;
  border: solid white 2px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Groceries</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="basket">
    <section id="basketItems"></section>
    <form>
      ITEM:
      <input id="a" type="text" id name="firstname"><br> PRICE:
      <input id="b" type="text" name="lastname">
      <button type="button" onclick="addList()">Button</button>
    </form>
  </section>
  <footer></footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```